# Make JasperReports keep a text box on the same page as the item immediately after the text box

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using iReport Designer 5.6.0.

I find that working with iReport and JasperReports is one of the skills that I learn and then quickly forget.

I have a subreport that shows three different "view" of the same piece of data.

1. Form View
2. Tabulated (Table) View
3. Plot (Image) View

Before each of the views I want to have a Title.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Jasper is sometimes putting page breaks between the title and its view.

Whats the best way to make JasperReports keep the title on the same page as the thing is titling?

The very fact that I'm calling my text boxes "titles" makes me think each view needs to be its own subreport.

Would that solve the problem?

Is there a "keep with next" box I need to check somewhere?

Comment: So is this all in the band title?

Comment: @Rika No its in Detail

Comment: @AlexK Whats was wrong with the iReport tag?  I want to know how to prevent the page break from iReport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you should be doing.

- Take a sub report for every view desired(this would simplify the design).
- Put your title and the desired view with data in the same band (this would force title to stick to the view) in sub report.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, I don't think this would help.  This is essentially what I have now, the "title" and the view ARE in the same band.  The title stays next to the view, but the problem is that Jasper decides it can put a page break in-between.

Comment: Your first suggestion of putting the title and view in its own sub-report may work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put them in its own group and check the box "Keep Together"

Comment: This sounds like what I want to achieve but when I group the items I don't see any properties on the group.  Is "Keep Together" available in 5.6 ?